# Do multiple canvas elements

Tags: javascript

I want to create multiple canvas elements with an id for each. What would the best approach be? Looking for a vanilla javascript solution.

```
var parent = document.createElement("parent");
var mycanvas1 = document.createElement("canvas");
mycanvas.id = "students";
document.getElementById("parent").appendChild(mycanvas1);

var mycanvas2 = document.createElement("canvas");
mycanvas.id = "classBadge";
document.getElementById("parent").appendChild(mycanvas2);

var mycanvas3 = document.createElement("canvas");
mycanvas.id = "classMaster";
document.getElementById("parent").appendChild(mycanvas3);
```

Comment: Maybe you can save the ids in an array. for(i:i<3;i++){mycanvas.id = array[i]}

Comment: `classMatser` ... `parnet` ... checked your spellings, did you?

Comment: @JanneckLange Yes that is an option. Thanks. Will wait for any other suggestions.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan well spotted! :) Fixed those in the post. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a reusable function that takes as argument the desired new canvas ID

```js
function createCanvas(canvasId) {
  const cvs = document.createElement("canvas");
  cvs.id = canvasId;
  document.getElementById('parent').appendChild(cvs);
}

createCanvas("students");
createCanvas("classBadge");
createCanvas("classMaster");
```

```css
canvas {outline: 1px solid red;}
```

```html
<div id="parent"></div>
```

Since probably you're going to use your canvas element after creation, you could additionally expand the above to create a callback and use it like:

```js
function createCanvas(canvasId, cb) {
  const cvs = document.createElement("canvas");
  cvs.id = canvasId;
  document.getElementById('parent').appendChild(cvs);
  if (cb) cb.call(cvs);
}

createCanvas("students", function() {
  // Canvas is created, use `this` to reference your new canvas Element 
  console.log(this.id);
});
```

```css
canvas {outline: 1px solid red;}
```

```html
<div id="parent"></div>
```

If you prefer not to use callbacks - than you could make your function `return` the created canvas:

```js
function createCanvas(canvasId, cb) {
  const cvs = document.createElement("canvas");
  cvs.id = canvasId;
  document.getElementById('parent').appendChild(cvs);
  return cvs;
}

const studentsCanvas = createCanvas("students");
console.log(studentsCanvas.id);
```

```css
canvas {outline: 1px solid red;}
```

```html
<div id="parent"></div>
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate this `if (cb) cb.call(cvs);` does? shouldn't it check if a canvas already exist by it's ID?

Comment: @jules2x the `if (cb)` checks if a `cb` argument exists. `.call(cvs)` calls the `cb` function passing `cvs` and binding it as the `this` function context. To make it bulletproof and prevent errors - you could first check if the `#parent` element exists in the DOM (to prevent errors) by using `const par = document.getElementById('parent'); if (!par) return;`

Comment: Cool... Thanks again Roko. :)

Answer (score 2):

You could store your different canvas ids inside an array and iterate over it, like in the example below.

*Note: You need to use the browser inspect tool to actually see the result, since the canvas elements are empty*

```js
// Create "parent" element and append it to the DOM
const parent = document.createElement("parent");
document.body.appendChild(parent)

// Iterate over an array to create new elements
const canvasIds = ['students', 'classBadge', 'classMaster']
canvasIds.forEach(id => {
    const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.id = id
    parent.appendChild(canvas);
})
```